# How can I lay out a rowkey or partition strategy for this scenario to prevent region hotspotting?

Tags: hbase, schema, region

I'm evaluating a set of data stores for a project that I am working on and one of the options is to store information in HBase. I'm aware that there are alternatives, but I wanted to give a shot of designing a schema in HBase for this use case.

I have a set of objects, each with an `objectId` (monotonically increasing) and each object has a set of custom properties (each property has a string `name` as its id).

In addition, I have some properties that are applicable to all objects (i.e. not tied to any particular `objectId`).

Each property can be a simple value or a list of values. For example, it could be something like an age (so the value is an `int`) or it could be a list of IPs in CIDR format.

Each property has the following information: `name`, `objectId` (this is NULL/NA if it is for all objects), `value` and some metadata (e.g. who made the change, etc).

My access patters are the following:

- Get all properties by `objectId`
- Update/put a new property with a new `name` and `objectId`
- Get a property with null `objectId` and `name`
- Update/put a new property with a new `name` and no `objectId`

My original idea was to split this into two tables (in the same HBase quorum). One will have all the properties that are tied to a `objectId` and the other for any properties that are applicable for all objects.

The row key would look like this:

**For properties that are for specific objects**

4 bytes sha1 of `objectId`: binary | `objectId`: long

There will be one CF that has all the properties (basically a JSON kvp)

**For properties that are for all objects**

4 bytes sha1 of `name`: binary | `name`: string

There will be one CF that has all the properties (basically a JSON kvp)

The regions will be pre-split and partitioned on the first byte of the row key (so in effect the top byte of the sha).

I did have one optimization for properties that are lists of things (e.g. list of IPs in CIDR format). In that case we would store the value in the key itself:

4 bytes sha1 of `name`: binary | `name`: string | value: string

So for example:

```
0x4eb9cce1|cidr|172.16.254.0/24
0x4eb9cce1|cidr|172.16.254.12/32
0x4eb9cce1|cidr|172.16.254.2/31
0xae999552|name|joe
0xae999552|name|matt
```

**CONCERNS**

My biggest concern with this idea is region hotspotting. My idea of taking a hash of the `objectId` was to avoid this. And I think that strategy will work for properties on objects.

But the issue is with properties that are not associated with any specific object. Because the hash is on the name and not some increasing ID, it will continue to hotspot in one particular region (assuming we have like a few thousand reads for CIDRs and a few hundred for names, the regions that serve 0x4eb9cce1 and 0xae999552 will get all the traffic and none in any of the other regions). Even if the region is pre-partioned to three regions that are keyed off of the first byte of the key (which will always be a-z), if I only have names that don't fill out the range, then it will show hotspotting.

I thought about reversing the row key but that only works if I store the value in the row key and it makes one of the access patterns (read all the values for a particular property in one scan) impossible.

**QUESTION**

Is there a different way to lay out the row key that I am missing which would prevent region hotspotting?

Is there a different partition strategy I can adopt which will allow me to keep my current row key but avoid hotspotting?

Also are there any drawbacks to consolidating the two tables into one?